# SSL3 error when requesting connection using TLS 1.2

Tags: tls, openssl

I've come across several hosts that throw SSL3 handshake errors even though I explicitly request TLS 1.2. Why is this? Am I using the `openssl` client wrong?

```
$ openssl s_client -tls1_2 -connect i-d-images.vice.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
140735150146384:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1472:SSL alert number 40
140735150146384:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:656:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1444078671
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In SSL/TLS, the client does not request a specific protocol version; the client *announces* the maximum protocol version that it supports, and then the server chooses the protocol version that will be used. Your client does not tell "let's use TLS 1.2"; it says "I know *up to* TLS 1.2".

A client *may* have its own extra requirements, but there is no room to state them in the `ClientHello` message. If the client wants to do TLS 1.2 only, then he must announce "up to TLS 1.2" in its `ClientHello`, *and* also close the connection if the server responds with a message that says anything else than "let's do TLS 1.2". In your case, things did not even reach that point: the server responded with a fatal alert 40 ("handshake_failure", see [the standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.2)). As @dave_thompson_085 points out, this is due to a lack of [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication): this is an extension by which the client documents in its `ClientHello` message the *name* of the target server. SNI is needed by some servers because they host several SSL-enabled sites on the same IP address, and need that parameter to know which certificate they should use. The command-line tool `openssl s_client` can send an SNI with an explicit `-servername` option.

As @Steffen explained, SSL 3.0 and all TLS versions are quite similar and use the same record format (at least in the early stage of the handshake) so OpenSSL tends to reuse the same functions. Note that since the server does not respond with a `ServerHello` at all, the protocol version is not yet chosen, and SSL 3.0 is still, at least conceptually, a possibility at that early point of the handshake.

Answer (score 10):

`ssl3_read_bytes` and `ssl3_writes_bytes` deal with SSL3-style frames. These are the same with later versions, i.e. TLS1.x. Thus the same functions get used, even though their names might suggest a different thing. There is no specific `tls1_read_bytes` function or similar.

Comment: This server, like many today, apparently requires SNI (Server Name Indication), which is not the default for `openssl s_client`. Add `-servername i-d-images.vice.com`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Is there a way to know that the server requires SNI?

Comment: @richid: see the [SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=i-d-images.vice.com&s=54.192.32.158): "This site works only in browsers with SNI support."

Comment: @richid: and also, adding the `-servername` option actually allows connection to proceed (try it !).